# Wrong URL's when overwriting to_params in Rails and using url_for or polymorphic_url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm overwriting to_params in a model to display SEO friendly URL's. The problem is, that when generating the URL for a nested resource it seems the to_params is also called resulting in a routing error:

```
#routes.rb
  resources :recipes do
    resources :ratings, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end
```

When I'm using `url_for([recipe, rating])`, the generated URL looks like this:

```
/recipes/2-name-of-the-recipe/ratings
```

Is there someway to fix either the way the URL is built or prevent the call to to_params on the model?

Comment: What would you like the url to look like?  And, why have a to_param method if you're not using it in this situation?

Comment: Well the pretty URI is for displaying the individual recipes. I need this kind of link to be able to submit rating for this specific recipe. I need to build the link that way since ratings is polymorphic... so this is actually the only reason I'm using the nested resource.

Comment: You should be able to use this uri for rating.  It will still route to the rating controller and you'll have access to a params[:recipe_id] that will work when you do a `Recipe.find()`.  Any reason why it wouldn't work?

Comment: Yeah, it did seem to work, but I was getting a routing error because I was doing a GET instead of a POST and blaimed it on the URI. Thanks anyways!